# método de otro formulario no hace nada

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un punto de venta en Windows Forms pero surge un problema un poco raro.

Tengo un método para que varios formularios se acoplen (o abran en un panel). Este funciona bien en el formulario principal pero cuando trato de usar desde otro formulario este no hace nada.

Metodo para acoplar los formularios al panel en el formulario principal:

```
public void AbrirFrom(object fromhijo)
{
    if (this.contenedor.Controls.Count > 0)
        this.contenedor.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    Form fh = fromhijo as Form;
    fh.TopLevel = false;
    fh.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.contenedor.Controls.Add(fh);
    this.contenedor.Tag = fh;
    fh.Show();
}
```

Formulario de ventas:

```
// Aquí es donde llamo el método por medio de un botón pero este no hace nada 



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Form1 form1 = new Form1();  

    form1.AbrirFrom(new Productos());

}
```

Al dar click en el botón para que se ejecute el método no hace nada. ¿Por qué?

Comment: Porqué envías new Productos() en vez de enviar el form ya creado? this.Productos o lo equivalente

Comment: lo envió asi por que en el From principal me funciona

Comment: `public void btnProductos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AbrirFrom(new Productos());
        }`

Comment: Que tipo de objeto es contenedor un split container, tool script container?

Comment: Es un panel como tal